# How do I get easy_install to use the right version of setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, easy-install

The latest version of setuptools (3.5.1) is installed in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages. But when I use easy_install, it uses setuptools version 0.6c12dev_r88846 inside /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the older versions of setuptools.

Sometime it is not so easy and it might need to try:

- removing it by installation program you used to install it (`brew`?, `apt-get`...)
- deleting it manually from directories incl. scripts, which are installed in your system (finding them by `which` setuptools)
- finally you shall reinstall `setuptools`

If I remember well, installation instructions for setuptools are asking to remove old version first.

I would even recommend:

1. remove the old `setuptools` completely
2. remove the latest `setuptools` completely
3. remove `pip`
4. install `pip` by means of `get_pip.py` as described here: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html#install-pip
5. install setuptools by `$ pip install setuptools`

Even if these steps sound complex, you shall do that, otherwise you will run into strange problems sooner or later.